# How do I use a search bar to sort my NSFetchedResults data without it crashing on fetchedRC.performFetch(), while updating tableview? UPDATED

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchcontroller

My data loads fine before trying to search but then as soon as I start typing into the search bar it crashes when calling `try fetchedRC.performFetch()`

I have tried Googling and changing the code around but nothing seems to be working.

This is my setup for getting the data from the one-to-many relationship with the data in CoreData.

```
func setupFetchedResultsController() {
    //fetchedRC = nil
    let request = Item.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Item>

    if !currentSearchText.isEmpty && !(currentSearchText == " ") {
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "list.name CONTAINS[c] \(currentSearchText)", parentObj)
    } else {
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "list = %@", parentObj)
    }

    //list CONTAINS[c] \(currentSearchText)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.isComplete), ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    do {
        fetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try fetchedRC.performFetch()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    fetchedRC.delegate = self
}
```

This is my updateSearchResults function

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    currentSearchText = text
    //fetchedRC = nil
    setupFetchedResultsController()
}
```

I have it set up so there is one parent list and many child items. What I expect to happen is to have the children be show that contain what the user enters into the search bar. So as the user types more into the search bar it updates and refines the search more. What actually happens is that it crashes when calling the `try fetchedRC.performFetch()`. What would be a way to solve this problem? I am new to doing this with FetchedResultsController as well.

This is the error message it gives when it crashes too: CoreData: `error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x28180cee0> , unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (list CONTAINS[c] A) (LHS and RHS both keypaths) with userInfo of (null)`

And as a note I also know that where it says `list.name` in `request.predicate`, is not proper I just did that as a place holder hoping it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, hopefully this helps anyone else with this problem too.

```
func setupFetchedResultsController() {

    let request = Item.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Item>

    //This line simplified just to help it be more reliable
    if (currentSearchText.count > 0) {
        // Line Updated and Fixed Problem
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "list = %@ && name CONTAINS %@", parentObj, currentSearchText)
    } else {
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "list = %@", parentObj)
    }

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.isComplete), ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        fetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try fetchedRC.performFetch()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    fetchedRC.delegate = self
}
```